# Diffie Hellman key exchange between C# and C++ on Windows

Tags: c#, c++, windows, diffie-hellman, public-key-exchange

I want to use the `Diffie Hellman` algorithm to securely exchange keys between a `C++` server an a `C#` client which both are running on `Windows`. I tried using `ECDiffieHellmanCng` in `C#` to generate a public key as follows:

```
ECDiffieHellmanCng diffieHellman = new ECDiffieHellmanCng
{
    KeyDerivationFunction = ECDiffieHellmanKeyDerivationFunction.Hash,
    HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256
};

byte[] publicKey = diffieHellman.PublicKey.ToByteArray(); // 140 bytes
```

Furthermore, I'm deriving the `AES key` using the following code:

```
var cngKey = CngKey.Import(publicKey, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob);
var aesKey = diffieHellman.DeriveKeyMaterial(cngKey); // 32 bytes
```

This works well in a `C#` context, however I need it to interact with `C++`.

Is there any `C++` library or code which is compatible with `ECDiffieHellmanCng`? I looked into `Crypto++` [but it wants me to generate a `p`, `q`, and `g` as well as the public key size being `128` bytes](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Diffie-Hellman) which looks like it's not compatible with my `C#` key exchange method.

Any other suggestions or code examples for performing the key exchange are welcome regardless.

Comment: **1) Do you realy need to generate server keys on the fly per each client?** It does not look right to me. Clients should somehow trust server's public key on connect (either have pub key hard-coded or use third-party channel to check it), right? **2) Can't you just use TLS and avoid meddling with low level stuff?**

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny: I don't really need to but I thought just implementing `Diffie-Hellman` with `AES` would be easy enough, apparently not. Maybe setting up `TLS` for the server and client is more viable and standard. I will try this as well but it could be another can of worms due to different technologies having to interact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I simply wanted an encrypted connection, going with [`OpenSSL`](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Simple_TLS_Server) was the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you a bit?

```
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "openssl/dh.h"
#include "openssl/bn.h"
#include "openssl/pem.h";
using namespace std;

DH *dhp = NULL;

static const std::string base64_chars =
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
"0123456789+/";

static inline bool is_base64(unsigned char c) {
    return (isalnum(c) || (c == '+') || (c == '/'));
}

std::string base64_encode(unsigned char const* bytes_to_encode, unsigned int in_len) {
    std::string ret;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    unsigned char char_array_3[3];
    unsigned char char_array_4[4];

    while (in_len--) {
        char_array_3[i++] = *(bytes_to_encode++);
        if (i == 3) {
            char_array_4[0] = (char_array_3[0] & 0xfc) >> 2;
            char_array_4[1] = ((char_array_3[0] & 0x03) << 4) + ((char_array_3[1] & 0xf0) >> 4);
            char_array_4[2] = ((char_array_3[1] & 0x0f) << 2) + ((char_array_3[2] & 0xc0) >> 6);
            char_array_4[3] = char_array_3[2] & 0x3f;

            for (i = 0; (i < 4); i++)
                ret += base64_chars[char_array_4[i]];
            i = 0;
        }
    }

    if (i)
    {
        for (j = i; j < 3; j++)
            char_array_3[j] = '\0';

        char_array_4[0] = (char_array_3[0] & 0xfc) >> 2;
        char_array_4[1] = ((char_array_3[0] & 0x03) << 4) + ((char_array_3[1] & 0xf0) >> 4);
        char_array_4[2] = ((char_array_3[1] & 0x0f) << 2) + ((char_array_3[2] & 0xc0) >> 6);
        char_array_4[3] = char_array_3[2] & 0x3f;

        for (j = 0; (j < i + 1); j++)
            ret += base64_chars[char_array_4[j]];

        while ((i++ < 3))
            ret += '=';

    }

    return ret;

}
std::string base64_decode(std::string const& encoded_string) {
    int in_len = encoded_string.size();
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int in_ = 0;
    unsigned char char_array_4[4], char_array_3[3];
    std::string ret;

    while (in_len-- && (encoded_string[in_] != '=') && is_base64(encoded_string[in_])) {
        char_array_4[i++] = encoded_string[in_]; in_++;
        if (i == 4) {
            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                char_array_4[i] = base64_chars.find(char_array_4[i]);

            char_array_3[0] = (char_array_4[0] << 2) + ((char_array_4[1] & 0x30) >> 4);
            char_array_3[1] = ((char_array_4[1] & 0xf) << 4) + ((char_array_4[2] & 0x3c) >> 2);
            char_array_3[2] = ((char_array_4[2] & 0x3) << 6) + char_array_4[3];

            for (i = 0; (i < 3); i++)
                ret += char_array_3[i];
            i = 0;
        }
    }

    if (i) {
        for (j = i; j < 4; j++)
            char_array_4[j] = 0;

        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            char_array_4[j] = base64_chars.find(char_array_4[j]);

        char_array_3[0] = (char_array_4[0] << 2) + ((char_array_4[1] & 0x30) >> 4);
        char_array_3[1] = ((char_array_4[1] & 0xf) << 4) + ((char_array_4[2] & 0x3c) >> 2);
        char_array_3[2] = ((char_array_4[2] & 0x3) << 6) + char_array_4[3];

        for (j = 0; (j < i - 1); j++) ret += char_array_3[j];
    }

    return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    BIGNUM* priv_key = NULL;
    BIGNUM* apub_key = NULL;
    BIGNUM* p = NULL;
    BIGNUM* g = NULL;
    std::string userPubKey;
    std::string prime;
    std::string generator;

    if (argc < 6) {
        printf("%s", "Missing parameters: -p, -key -g");
        return -1;
    }

    //Process parameters
    int count;
    for (count = 1; count < argc; count+=2)
    {
        std::string param = (string)argv[count];

        if (strcmpi(param.c_str(), "-p") == 0) {
            prime = (string)argv[count+1];
        }
        else if (strcmpi(param.c_str(), "-key") == 0) {
            userPubKey = (string)argv[count + 1];
        }
        else if (strcmpi(param.c_str(), "-g") == 0) {
            generator = (string)argv[count+1];
        }
    }

    //Set public key of remote User
    BN_hex2bn(&apub_key, userPubKey.c_str());

    DH *dhp = DH_new();
    if (dhp == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    
    //Set Prime and Generator
    BN_hex2bn(&p, prime.c_str());
    BN_dec2bn(&g, generator.c_str());
    DH_set0_pqg(dhp, p, NULL, g);

    if (DH_generate_key(dhp) != 1) {
        printf("%s", "Error generating keys.");
        return -1;
    }

    //Print Public Key as Hex
    const BIGNUM* exportPublic = DH_get0_pub_key(dhp);
    printf("Public Key: %s\r\n", BN_bn2hex(exportPublic));

    //Calculate secret
    char buf[256] = { 0 };
    unsigned char* abuf = NULL;
    int alen = DH_size(dhp);
    abuf = (unsigned char*)OPENSSL_malloc(alen);

    int aout = DH_compute_key(abuf, apub_key, dhp);
    printf("\r\nThe shared secret is:\r\n");
    std::string encoded = base64_encode(abuf, aout);
    printf("%s\r\n", encoded.c_str());

    DH_free(dhp);
    p = NULL;
    g = NULL;
    abuf = NULL;
}
```